# How to set a values for combobox based on a clicked value from another combobox using javafx

Tags: java, javafx, combobox

I am new to javafx and want to set a new values for another combobox based on the selected value of the first combobox in real-time.
I have tried on this code but not works

```
@FXML
public void A(ActionEvent event) {
String a[] = {"A","B","C"}; 
list2 = FXCollections.observableArrayList(a);
ChunitS.setItems(list2);
if (ChunitS.getValue() == (null)) {
return;
} else {
list1 = FXCollections.observableArrayList(ChunitS.getValue().toString());
ChassS.setItems(list1);
}
}
```

if I chose "A" in the first combobox, the second combobox should be updated to have the value "A" in it.

Comment: Just register a listener with the `valueProperty()` of the first combo box, and in it call `setItems()` on the second combo box. It's not really clear which part you are stuck with. Also: please do not post links to code, and [do not post images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question). Include code directly in your question, [properly formatted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).

Comment: Sorry I have updated the question and should be now more clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try to use `String output = ChunitS.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().toString();` inside the on action first combobox function in order to get the selected. Then set the selected value in the second combobox. Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

You can add listener to first ComboBox:

```
@FXML private ComboBox<String> combo1,combo2;

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
   //Init ComboBox items
   combo1.setItems(
       FXCollections.observableArrayList(new String[]{"A","B"})
   );
   combo2.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList());
   //add ActionListener for Example
   combo1.setOnAction(e->{
       combo2.getItems().add(
              combo1.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem()
        );
    });
}
```

, or  use button (@FXML 'onAction' reference):

```
@FXML
public void handleButtonA(ActionEvent event) {
        combo2.getItems().add(
              combo1.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem()
        );
    }
```